# How can you use session variable to determine view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-variables, partial-views

I have my global.asax setup with the following Session_Start:

```
protected void Session_Start()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("sourceCode", "default");
}
```

On my controller I have the following:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sourceCode)
{
    if (sourceCode != null && sourceCode != "default")
    {
        Session["sourceCode"] = sourceCode;
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to display different partial layouts based on this session variable. What is the proper way to do this? Can I load a partial view from the controller or do I need to handle that on the view?

This is a variable that I want to use site wide to determine special pricing and landing page creatives. Do I have to set this same structure up on every single controller or is there a more global way of doing this?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the convention of MVC, controller should decide which view it should open. For this in controller you have code like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sourceCode)
{
if (sourceCode != null && sourceCode != "default")
{
Session["sourceCode"] = sourceCode;
ViewData["PartialView"] = "partialviewname1";               
}
else
{
ViewData["PartialView"] = "partialviewname2";                
}
return View();
}
```

and in view you can write code something like this:

```
<div>
@Html.Partial(Convert.ToString(ViewData["PartialView"]))
</div>
```

and if you have decide which partial view you have to load on each and every request then you can write above logic in global action filter. Global action filter get executed before any requested action method. To know more about global action filter you can explore this link.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the layout in all the pages, you might want to add the logic in the layout file. There, you will add something like that (assuming razor)

```
@if(HttpContext.Current.Session["someValue"]){
@*render some partial*@
}else{
@*render some other partial*@
}
```